# getting requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4\r\n')) when using proxy with requests Python

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy

I am trying to use a server i have set up earlier as a proxy when sending requests in python:

```
import requests



proxies = {
    'http': 'http://user:pass@ip:port',
}


s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = proxies

# Make the HTTP request through the session.
r = s.get('http://www.showmemyip.com/')
```

but get this error:

```
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4\r\n'))
```

It looks like it wants ssh authentification but why? I specify user and password shouldn't it be enough?